# What is the main rotor speed (RPM) of Sikorsky CH-53E Super Stallion?

Tags: rotorcraft, tail-rotor

In order to calculate the tip speed ($V_{tip} = ω×R$) of [Sikorsky CH-53E Super Stallion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_CH-53E_Super_Stallion), I need to find the rotation speed of the main rotor for the forward flight case. Can someone provide an answer with a reliable source? Also can someone provide the tail rotor RPM too?

Comment: The blade's tip can't move any faster than the speed of sound, at maximum forward speed. Its airspeed will be tip speed + forward speed. Have you tried calculating it back from that?

Comment: Typically a main rotor's tip speed is around  210m/s. With a radius of 12m this gives an $\omega$ of 17.5 rad/s i.e. 167rpm

Comment: @sophit That's seems rather slow. Most helicopters are in the range of 200-400 RPM. A Bell Huey is 320ish.  A 206 is around 400.  IIRC a Blackhawk is in the 250 range.

Comment: Just going by the published specs. https://sikorskyarchives.com/home/sikorsky-product-history/helicopter-innovation-era/sikorsky-s-70a-uh-60l-black-hawk-family/ Tip speed 725fps @258 RPM.

Comment: @JohnK: do you have something similar for the CH-53? Anyway if you scale 258rpm from  8 to 12m you get the (estimated) 170rpm of the CH-53.

Comment: Oh crap. When I skimmed over the title originally, "Blackhawk" went into my head, not Stallion.  Ooops. Your figure of 167 wasn't that far off.  Says here 185 https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/tag/sikorsky-ych-53a-sea-stallion/

Answer (score 3):

It says [here](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/tag/sikorsky-ych-53a-sea-stallion/) 185 RPM and 792 RPM for the A model.  For the E model with blades are 1.33 meters longer, you need to drop the rotor RPM to about 170 to keep the same blade tip speed. Note that those are nominal speeds; there will be a green arc RPM +/- range that brackets that value with a minimum and maximum RPM limit.

Comment: That's the value for the CH-53**A** (aka *stallion*) which has a different rotor than the **E** (aka *super stallion*) version: 11m radius and 6 blades vs. 12m radius and 7 blades. If we scale the rpm value according to the different radius, we get 170rpm that should be the correct value for the **E** version. @JohnK can you please update the answer? 

Answer (score 2):

Sikorsky CH-53E

Main rotor tip speed = 732 ft/sec
Main rotor radius = 39.5’
Main rotor rpm = 177

Tail rotor tip speed = 733 ft/sec
Tail rotor radius = 10’
Tail rotor rpm = 700

Vtip = (R x RPM) / 9.5493

RPM = (Vtip  x 9.5493)/R

Vtip  = ft/sec
R =  Rotor Radius feet
RPM = Rotor turns per/min

Ref: Helicopter Performance, Stability, and Control
Appendix B and pg.11
by  Raymond W. Prouty  (Author)
ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1575242095
ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1575242095
https://vertipedia.vtol.org/biographies/getBiography/biographyID/88